# Playing media from ftp server

Tags: router, video, ftp, samba

I have a question re access to ftp server from a media player (hardware, not the windows media player).

I think about buying a router with ftp server function to take the load off from my quite old pc. However I am concerned that my media player which gets access to the same ftp folders via samba (running on the same veteran pc) will not be able to access the ftp directly.

So as a result of my upgrade I will end up having to mount the ftp folders from router to my old pc and sharing these folders again via samba with the media player... Which does not look like a good idea to me as my motivation is to offload my pc first...

However that makes me think that the router producers should have had in mind media sharing so there should be an easy and conventional option of setting the ftp router speak to the media player.

Can someone please enlighten me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most home gateway routers that support drive sharing *do* support SMB. Some also support AFP for Macs and DLNA for media streaming. The ones that support FTP usually have it for WAN file transfers when the ISP blocks SMB.

Are you sure your router only supports FTP? What is the make and model? Sounds like you just need to upgrade to a decent router instead of a bargain-basement model. Or maybe see if an open source firmware distro supports it, like DD-WRT, OpenWrt, or Tomato.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at this one but in the 'spec' they says only ftp-word: http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-WR1043ND-Wireless-Printers-included/dp/B002YETVTQ/ref=sr_1_4?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1404521990&sr=1-4&keywords=tp-link+router it is worth getting full manual at least and checking available firmware

Comment: Ok cool. It seems that OpenWrt can be installed on this one and then one can even ssh to the router...! Thanks for the lead!